# How can I change VC background color from another view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I have two storyboards and I need from VC form second Storyboard change the background color on VC from the main storyboard.
I use this code in button on second storyboard:

```
let vc = FirstScreenVC()
vc.view.backgroundColor = .black
```

and have this error:

> "Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value"

in FirstScreenVC file at viewDidLoad.

Debug tells that 3 UIElement on FirstScreenVC equals **nil**, but I see it and it first what load in app.

Comment: Can you provide a better example of your code?

Comment: http://www.programmingios.net/dont-make-a-new-instance-by-mistake/

Answer (score 2):

You have instantiated a new FirstScreenVC which is not the one that you're seeing. Depending on how your stack is set, you need to either fetch the existing viewController, or pass the reference to it to the viewController that needs to do the change.

Answer (score 0):

If you use navigation controller, you can use prepareForSegue method when going to other page.

```swift
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let vc = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
        vc.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    }
```